# distributed enterprise integration pattern

Tags: apache-camel, enterprise, integration-patterns

i'm developing a cloud application that uses camel. It sends a message to a SQS queue which is consumed by a web service. Is there a solution that can control each camel producer service when the application scales? i.e. start/stop routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can start and stop routes as long as you have an handle to the camel context and know the route ids. Also consider resume/suspend route.

Take a look at http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html